# Attempting to query with graphql where id is

Tags: graphql, gatsby, strapi

I need to get a query using graphql in strapi/gatsby where id is {id}.
According to the documentation [found here](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-strapi/#querying-data) you query all like so:

```
{
  allStrapiArticle {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        content
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This works and I'm able to query however I'd like to get only one Article where id is {id};

I have tried:

```
    {
  allStrapiArticle(id: "4") {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        content
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And also:

```
{
  allStrapiArticle {
    edges {
      node(id: "4") {
        id
        title
        content
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Both of the above give me an error.  Any idea how I can achieve this?

Comment: Does it work if you do just `{node(id: "4") {... on Article { id title content } }}` without all the other stuff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
    {
  allStrapiArticle(filter: {id: {eq: "4" }}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        title
        content
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`elemMatch` filter might be useful for your use case as well.

Check the `localhost:8000/___graphql` playground to test your queries and filters.

More references:

- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/query-filters/
- https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/graphql-reference/